# Struts ActionSupport and static method and variable

Tags: struts2

i am very new to struts and jsp and i have to make a assignment in which i have to make guestbook app

but place stuck in jsp view when i amm try to  iterate over arrayList in which gust message store and list is static always return null
my jspview is

```
<body>
    <a href="<s:url action="GuestBook"/>">Click </a>here for sign guest book<br/><br/>
    <table>
        <s:iterator value="messages">
            <tr>
                <td><s:property value="when"/><br/></td>
                <td><s:property value="guest"/><br/></td>
                <td><s:property value="message"/><br/></td>
            </tr>
        </s:iterator>
    </table>
</body>
```

and action class is

```
public class GuestBookAction extends ActionSupport {
    private String guest, message;
    private String when = new Date().toString();
    private static  ArrayList<GuestBook> messages = new ArrayList<GuestBook>();

    static {
        messages.add(new GuestBook("1","1","1"));
        messages.add(new GuestBook("2","1","1"));
        messages.add(new GuestBook("3","1","1"));
        messages.add(new GuestBook("4","1","1"));
        messages.add(new GuestBook("5","1","1"));
    }

    @Override
    public String execute(){
        boolean add = messages.add(new GuestBook(this.getGuest(), this.getMessage(), this.getWhen()));
        if (add) {
            return SUCCESS;
        } else {
            return ERROR;
        }
    }

    public String getGuest() {
        return guest;
    }

    public void setGuest(String guest) {
        this.guest = guest;
    }

    public String getMessage() {
        return message;
    }

    public void setMessage(String message) {
        this.message = message;
    }

    public  ArrayList<GuestBook> getMessages() {
        return messages;
    }

    public  void setMessages(ArrayList<GuestBook> messages) {
        GuestBookAction.messages = messages;
    }

    public static Logger getLOG() {
        return LOG;
    }

    public static void setLOG(Logger LOG) {
        ActionSupport.LOG = LOG;
    }

    public String getWhen() {
        return when;
    }

    public void setWhen(String when) {
        this.when = when;
    }

}
```

If I don't iterate it works fine. 
thanks

Comment: How do you access the JSP page the first time? Through an action?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to be an issue with Struts 2 configuration. It is said that Struts 2 does not support the access for static variables. But, you can configure it in the properties file. Please refer the links below:

http://struts.apache.org/2.0.14/docs/strutsproperties.html

In the above link, see the last configuration. This is the thing to be changed.

See the link below:

http://struts.apache.org/2.x/docs/ognl-basics.html#OGNLBasics-Accessingstaticproperties

Comment: There's a public accessor for the static property; the static part isn't relevant.

Comment: Please see this statement "By default, Struts 2 is configured to disallow this--to enable OGNL's static member support you must set the struts.ognl.allowStaticMethodAccess constant to true"

Comment: There's a reasonable chance I wrote that statement. Doesn't change the fact that in the code above there's no static access going on: there's an instance getter method, so allowing static access isn't relevant.

Comment: I'd be curious if the OP even tried this before accepting the answer. It shouldn't have made a bit of different.